# Execute goal on parent after children complete

Tags: maven-2, cruisecontrol

I have a multi-module maven project (several levels of nesting).  Normally, when I execute a maven build (like `mvn install` or whatever), maven will run all the goals for the parent project *before* proceeding with the children.

I want to be able to define a goal that runs on the parent, but not until all of the children have been processed.  Is there a way to do this?

Specifically, what I want to do is run an `exec:exec` goal which recurses down the filesystem looking for test result files and copies them to a central location for aggregation by our CI system (cruisecontrol).  So, alternative solutions to this problem are also welcome :)

UPDATE: I forgot to mention one requirement: I need the exec goal to run regardless of whether the build is successful or not.

Comment: Regarding the update, couldn't that be the responsibility of the CI tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the other answers and my own subsequent investigation, it doesn't look like what I described is possible with Maven.

However, I was able to solve my problem, although the solution is specific to cruisecontrol.  Basically, I bound my exec goal to the pre-site phase then specified pre-site as the `sitegoal` in my cruisecontrol configuration.  The `sitegoal` runs after the main goal, and does so regardless of whether the build succeeds or not.

I imagine other CI systems offer something similar..

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to do things from the parent at the end of a multi-modules build (this is just not how things work). However, did you consider adding a module (that could be of type pom) depending on all child projects (so it will be the "last" project in a reactor build) and run `exec:exec` in this module? I may be missing something be I don't see why this wouldn't work.

Comment: This works in basic situations, but fails in case when modules are e.g. Spring Boot Applications. Those don't make good dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like a reporting plugin. Creating a Maven plugin is actually quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a antrun copy step attached to the verify phase of each sub project to copy the results up to the parent location. You could then have a similiar step in the parent to do the CI aggregation.

Alternatively, you could have each sub project do its own CI integration using a simliar techneque.

We currenyly use the technique to generate websphere ejb stubs for a jar, amongst other things.